# Does Mona's Transmutation ability let you earn duplicates of Unique cards?

Tags: shovel-knight, shovel-knight-king-of-cards

In *Shovel Knight: King of Cards*, there are one-of-a-kind Unique cards that can normally only be earned by beating their owner in Joustus and picking the card as a prize. However, I noticed that Mona's Transmutation ability could copy unique cards, letting her play a second copy of a unique card you own.

If you beat Mona after she copies a card with Transmutation, what happens if you select the copied card as a prize? Does this let you earn multiple copies of Unique cards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Transmuted cards are returned to their original form once a match is completed. This prevents you from getting duplicates of unique cards.

[image: Transmuted card returning to original form]